# How do I ship multiple `dotnet new` templates inside a single NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-new

I have a `dotnet new` template project that consists of three templates:

- Library
- Headless .NET Core service
- ASP.NET Core Web Application

Project source can be found here (it's FOSS): https://github.com/petabridge/petabridge-dotnet-new/

I've followed the best practices outlined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates and created a `.csproj` that targets all three templates:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageType>Template</PackageType>
    <PackageVersion>1.0</PackageVersion>
    <PackageId>Petabridge.Templates</PackageId>
    <Title>Petabridge.Templates</Title>
    <Authors>Petabridge</Authors>
    <Description>Professional .NET Core templates complete with CI, Docs, and more. Supports library, Akka.NET, and ASP.NET Core application types.</Description>
    <PackageTags>dotnet-new;templates;petabridge;akka;</PackageTags>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageReleaseNotes></PackageReleaseNotes>
    <IncludeContentInPack>true</IncludeContentInPack>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <ContentTargetFolders>content</ContentTargetFolders>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="templates\**\*" Exclude="templates\**\bin\**;templates\**\obj\**" />
    <Compile Remove="**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Live version of this source can be found here: https://github.com/petabridge/petabridge-dotnet-new/blob/dev/src/Petabridge.Templates.csproj

After I run the build script and check the package output, I can see the NuGet package that was built as part of the package output definitely contains all three templates inside of it - you can download the signed version of this package from the Github Release on this repository: https://github.com/petabridge/petabridge-dotnet-new/releases/tag/1.0.1

My issue is, that when I install these templates onto my machine using the latest .NET Core 3.0 SDK, I only see the third template (web application) show up in the install list:

```
PS> dotnet new -i "Petabridge.Templates::*"
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why does only one template show up when I install this package? All relevant source, template configs, et al can be found through the click-through on the repository links I included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by having a different value for groupIdentity inside the template.json file of each template.

https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/%22Runnable-Project%22-Templates#configuration

> groupIdentity (optional)
>
> The ID of the group this template belongs to. When combined with the
>   tags section, this allows **multiple templates to be displayed as
>   one**, with the the decision for which one to use being presented as a
>   choice in each one of the pivot categories (keys).